# Kill all threads when one of them has ended earlier C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, sudoku

I am looking for ways how to resolve of my problem in C++ .

**Detailed description (brief description is below):**

I am writing the sudoku solver. I have already created bruteforce method (check which numbers have already been used in the same row, column and square) and now I want to wright "heuristic" multithread method. This heuristics means that when the program finds cell with >1 possible values, it puts first possible value to this cell and try bruteforce on it. If it leads to right  - great! If no, it tries second possible value for this cell. And so on, before the array of possible values ends. Then it tries to do the same with second blank cell etc. Under 'multithread' I mean that the first thread will run this algorithm starting from the first blank cell, the second thread will start from the second blank cell and so on. So the problem is:

**Brief description:**

I want to create *n* threads, and each of them has the same probability to find right solution and return it back to the main thread (or write it by ref to the initial variable, which is waiting for it in main thread). I am looking for the way how to stop all threads if one of them told me (me == main thread) that it has found the solution.

**P.S.** If you have any ideas how to improve my algorithm, I would be glad to hear them from you.

**UPD** Running it only on GNU/Linux

Comment: When you learned about threads, you should've also learned about mutexes and condition variables. In this case, a simple `bool`, with a mutex protecting it, will be sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: have a bool variable called foundSolution , have each thread look to see if it is set in each time round its main loop

Comment: Perhaps [std::atomic_bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) would be useful here.

Comment: You can of course hard-kill the thread, but that's OS-dependant and a really bad idea. Instead simply use a flag to terminate the loop running within the thread.

Comment: Killing threads is often a bad idea, but sending a message, setting an atomic flag, or otherwise telling the thread to politely return at the earliest convenience... What he said ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two general ways to go about this.

One way is to use a flag, and periodically poll the flag.  The "safe" way to do that is to use an atomic,

```
std::atomic<bool> complete;

// In your thread, when you find a solution…
complete.store(true);

// In your thread, when you want to know if another thread found a solution…
if (complete.load()) {
    // return early
}
```

The second way, which is far more difficult, is to actually kill the workers when one worker finds the solution.  The only reasonable safe way to do this is to run each worker in its own process and kill each worker process when a solution is found.

Comment: @ArtemKelpe Anywhere as long as is a singleton in all your application. As a static member of your SudokuSolver class, for instance.

Comment: @ArtemKelpe: The code above is fragmentary.  Just make sure you have one variable shared between all threads working on the same problem.

Comment: You can also use the more C++-like forms `complete = true;` and `if(complete)`.